# How do I use a javascript variable in the Filter Criteria for a DVWP?

Tags: javascript, filter, data-view-web-part, 2007

I am converting some numbers using Javascript and need to filter a list using these conversions.  I cannot do the conversions within SharePoint itself, so I had to use Designer and some Javascript.  I need to use the end variable, compare, in the filter criteria of my Data View Web Part.  I do not currently have it as a return value, but if needed, I can make the Javascript function return it.  How do I reference this variable in my Filter Criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script is going to run client side, so you can't filter the DVWP with the calculations. You can filter client side and either remove or hide the items in the DOM.

Comment: Could you recommend a source to hide items in the DOM?  Thanks.

Comment: Plenty of examples on the Web for that. Basically, you set display: hidden.